# How to add an Array element to an NSMutableArray which already contains another array Values?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

I have three different `NSMutableArray`, lets say `A`,`B`,and `C`. I am adding the `A` array to the `C` and from array `B` I need only one element. So i need to add that element to the `C` array. Please give me an idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   NSMutableArray *a;
   NSMutableArray *b;
   NSMutableArray *c;

   //somewhere they get initialized...

   [c addObject:a];
   [c addObject: [b objectAtIndex:n]];
```

Comment: I do not think that you can add a whole array using addObject. This will not give you a compile error as addObject accepts all Objects, but instead of having an array containing all elements from array a and c you would end up with an array containing all elements of c and the array a. Instead use `addObjectsFromArray:`

Comment: This adds array A as one object, I think he wants [C addObjectsFromArray:A];

Comment: @gebirgsbaerbel an object is an object

Comment: @ott of course, but as we both said it still will probably not what he expects

Answer (score 1):

```
int index;
NSArray *A, *B;
NSMutableArray *C = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:A];
[C addObject:[B objectAtIndex:index]];
```

Comment: Any previous existing objects in C are lost when doing it this way. How about addObjectsFromArray?

Comment: read again: I have three different NSMutableArray, lets say A,B,and C. I am adding the A array to the C ...

Answer (score 1):

```
[C addObjectsFromArray:A];
id o = [B objectAtIndex:0]; // first item, or find the item you're looking for
[C addObject:o];
```

That should do it. This assumes you've already alloc'd and init'd or otherwise own a created NSMutableArray for all of A, B and C.

Answer (score 1):

```
[c addObjectsFromArray:a];
[c addObject:[b objectAtindex:index];
```

Comment: [c addObjectsFromArray:a]; :-)

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
if (A.count != 0) {
    for (int i=0; i<=A.count-1; i++) {
        [C addObject:[A objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}
```

This will add all the object of array A in array C.

```
[C addObject:[B objectAtIndex:n]];
```

This insert an object of array B which pointed by index 'n' in array C.